# Convert integer to string within array

Tags: php

I have an unusual situation where depending on the value of active being 0 or 1 causing invalid JSON to be interpreted client side. How can I change value active from an int to string within the array so that json_encode is valid? Or is it something else entirely? Looking at both json outputs look identical...

Active and ID are both integers. Everything else is a string.

Interestingly enough, if active is 1 instead of 0 the JSON is valid and displays properly.

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 254,
    "name": "Test",
    "company": "Test",
    "email": "Test",
    "phone": "Test",
    "comments": "Test",
    "ticket": "Test",
    "assigned": "",
    "active": 0,
    "date_created": "2018-12-02 00:56:49"
  }
]
```

Code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, company, email, phone, comments, ticket, assigned, active, date_created FROM tickets_info");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result_array = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($result_array, $row);
}

header("Content-Type: application/json"); 

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

Comment: Please update your question with how the comparison is done client-side and the error that is thrown there. I don't see that the current JSON array that you have shared is invalid.

Comment: I receive valid json client-side when integers are converted to string. How can I convert id and active to strings within the array?

Comment: I copied the above json to an online validator and it said your json was valid. I don't think there is anything wrong with your server side code.

Answer (score 3):

As your question that you need to cast int to string

It's easy just cast it

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $row['id'] = (string) $row['id'] ;
       $row['active'] = (string) $row['active'] ;
       array_push($result_array, $row) ;
}
```

CASTING are very easy to change data type

We can cast following data type variable in PHP

`(int), (integer)` - cast to `integer`

`(bool), (boolean)` - cast to `boolean`

`(float), (double), (real)` - cast to `float`

`(string)` - cast to `string`

`(array)` - cast to `array`

`(object)` - cast to `object`

`(unset)` - cast to `NULL` (PHP 5)

Reference https://www.greycampus.com/codelabs/php/type-casting

Comment: Sorry, let me be clear. I would like to change id and active from integers to strings. How can this be done inside the array?

Comment: Please check answer I updated it with casting